# Poses a problem for/to

Tags: to-for

I keep seeing both versions and I can't find a definite answer from googling.

For example, which of these would be correct?

"Although this dilemma poses a problem **to** the proposed view..."

"Although this dilemma poses a problem **for** the proposed view..."

Comment: I would use _for;_ with _to_ it sounds as if the view itself cares.

Answer (score -1):

I believe both are acceptable, though the context is changed in each: "...to the proposed view..." tells me the problem affects the proposal *itself* where "...for the proposed view..." tells me the problem affects the *implementation* of the proposal.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! :)

Answer (score -1):

You can't ask which is *correct*, since neither of them is ungrammatical.

You can only ask which is more common. Specific contexts aside, the more common expression in general, at least according to [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=poses%20a%20problem%20to%2C%20poses%20a%20problem%20for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cposes%20a%20problem%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cposes%20a%20problem%20for%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cposes%20a%20problem%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cposes%20a%20problem%20for%3B%2Cc0) as related to the printed word, is *poses a problem* ***for***.

[image: poses a problem for]

Which of the two you use would be a matter of personal choice.

There can also be a subtle difference in interpretation, where *for* might be referencing something as it's being considered, while *to* could be thought of as affecting something after the fact. However, that's not always how it would be interpreted.